# I've move my site but URL still goes to the old site

Tags: redirect, urls

I purchased a site name through Wordpress.com and built a site there.

I then wanted to build a better site using Wordpress.org so paid to have a domain name transfer so that the site name and hosting was all in one place with 123-Reg.

I was told that the transfer of the name was successful and I can see the site name when I look in my 123-Reg control panel. I then set up a WordPress environment and built a site but when I enter the site name in Google I'm still seeing the old site I created in WordPress.com.

I went to 123-Reg to see why this was happening. They said my problem was with the WordPress.org install and they couldn't find the cause of the problem - they said "We can't help you we don't understand why this is happening".

I deleted everything to start again. I now have a basic Wordpress.org install with TwentySeventeen running so I know that none of my files are corrupt.

But still when I enter 'Blatantlylondon.com' into a search engine the old Wordpress.com site comes up. It's been three weeks now and am at a loss as what to do as 123-Reg can't help me.

Anyone? Please! Thanks.

Comment: I assume that when you enter your domain in browser that you get the new site. If true, then DNS (the thing that gets people to your site when they enter the domain name) is working properly (the nameservers are set up properly).

So if search results are showing old pages, and those links are 'not found',  then you need to resubmit your site to the webmaster tools (google, bing, whatever) so they can re-scan your content. Or add a plugin that will recreate and resubmit your sitemap file.

Comment: No when I enter my domain in a browser it goes to the old site. As Chris says I think its the DNS - I keep applying the correct DNS but when I go back (leaving 48 hours or more to take effect) the DNS is back to the old setting which says '123-Reg Holding/Forwarding'. Which I think is 123-Reg's problem not mine. But they're denying this and now have told me to 'get a web developer' as I clearly don't understand!!

Comment: By the way Rick forgot to say thanks on the last comment - apologies am a bit stressed over this. I think your advice to get a plugin that recreates and resubmits the sitemap file is a good one and I'll look into that and research what I need to do. Thank you!

Comment: Don't suppose you could point me in the right direction with any names? Thanks!

Comment: Re: nameservers - that is usually the problem with URLs going to the wrong place. There can be a delay in propagating any changes, but your domain registrar should be able to change it - or you can, via your login on the domain registrar. (Note that you have to change the nameservers at your domain registrar, wherever that is. Rightnow, your domain registrar is  http://www.domainbox.com , according to www.ddwhois.com .)  As for sitemaps, I use this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/xml-sitemap-feed/

Comment: Hi, I think there have been a few issues here I found out that my ICANN verification hadn't been completed (I didn't receive an email) so I've now done this through my cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The nameservers [listed for your domain](http://whois.domaintools.com/blatantlylondon.com) are still at wordpress.com - you need to go into the domain section of your 123-reg panel and [set those to 123-reg defaults](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Video/Domains/how-do-i-point-my-123-reg-domain-name-to-my-3rd-party-website-3874/).

Comment: Chris, I think you're right I've just said above that I keep changing the DNS to point away from the old website but then when I go back it's changed back to the Wordpress.com name servers. I've changed it now many times over a period of three weeks but still it goes back to '123-Reg Holding/Forwarding'. I was wondering if I need to change any PHP files or is it just the DNS?

Comment: Just the nameservers for the moment.

Comment: Yes - I think so too. This has all confirmed what I thought was going on but for some reason 123-Reg don't seem to want to admit that. Thank you for your help.